# Adding words between lines to an array

Tags: python

This is the content of my file:

```
david    C001 C002 C004 C005 C006 C007

*    C008 C009 C010 C011 C016 C017 C018

*    C019 C020 C021 C022 C023 C024 C025

anna C500 C521 C523 C547 C555 C556

*    C557 C559 C562 C563 C566 C567 C568

*    C569 C571 C572 C573 C574 C575 C576

*    C578

charlie    C701 C702 C704 C706 C707 C708

*    C709 C712 C715 C716 C717 C718
```

I want my output to be:

```
david=[C001,C002,C004,C005,C006,C007,C008,C009,C010,C011,C016,C017,C018,C019,C020,C021,C022,C023,C024,C025]

anna=[C500,C521,C523,C547,C555,C556,C557,C559,C562,C563,C566,C567,C568,C569,C571,C572,C573,C574,C575,C576,C578]

charlie=[C701,C702,C704,C706,C707,C708,C709,C712,C715,C716,C717,C718]
```

I am able to create:

```
david=[C001,C002,C004,C005,C006,C007]
anna=[C500,C521,C523,C547,C555,C556]
charlie=[C701,C702,C704,C706,C707,C708]
```

counting the number of words in a line and using line[0] as the array name and adding the remaining words to the array.
However, I don't know how to take the continuation of words in the next lines starting with "*" to the array.

Can anyone help?

Comment: Will it always be these three names? Please provide the code you came up with so far so answers can use it as a base.

Comment: How would you go about deciding in your head which person the line of text belongs to? The python solution is the exact same

Comment: you want your output in a text file, right?

Comment: you can use `david.extend('*    C008 C009 C010 C011 C016 C017 C018'.strip('*').split()` if line starts with `*`

Answer (score 1):

**NOTE**: This solution relies on `defaultdict` being ordered, which is something that was introduced on Python 3.6

Somewhat naive approach:

```py
from collections import defaultdict

# Create a dictionary of people
people = defaultdict(list)

# Open up your file in read-only mode
with open('your_file.txt', 'r') as f:
    # Iterate over all lines, stripping them and splitting them into words
    for line in filter(bool, map(str.split, map(str.strip, f))):
        # Retrieve the name of the person
        # either from the current line or use the name of the last person processed
        name, words = list(people)[-1] if line[0] == '*' else line[0], line[1:]
        # Add all remaining words to that person's record
        people[name].extend(words)


print(people['anna'])
# ['C500', 'C521', 'C523', 'C547', 'C555', 'C556', 'C557', 'C559', 'C562', 'C563', 'C566', 'C567', 'C568', 'C569', 'C571', 'C572', 'C573', 'C574', 'C575', 'C576', 'C578']
```

It also has the additional benefit of returning an empty `list` for unknown names:

```py
print(people['matt'])
# []
```

Answer (score 0):

You could read the lists into a dictionary using regular expressions:

```
import re
with open('file_name') as file:
    contents = file.read()
res_list = re.findall(r"[a-z]+\s+[^a-z]+",contents)
res_dict = {}
for p in res_list:
    elt = p.split()
    res_dict[elt[0]] = [e for e in elt[1:] if e != '*']

print(res_dict)
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured out a way myself. Thanks to the ones who gave their own solution. It gave me new perspective.

Below is my code:

```
persons_library={}
persons=['david','anna','charlie']
for i,person in enumerate(persons,start=0):
    persons_library[person]=[]

with open('data.txt','r') as f:
    for line in f:
        line=line.replace('*',"")
        line=line.split()
        for i,val in enumerate(line,start=0):
            if val in persons_library:
                key=val
            else:
                persons_library[key].append(val)
    print(persons_library)
```